Super-additivity of $\text{ex}(n, \pi)$
I have 2 basic questions from the paper of Fox here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.8378,  in the Introduction (page 3).

I don't really understand what super-additivity of $\text{ex}(n, \pi)$ means here. Please fill me in. Initially I guessed that the definition is:


Super-additivity of $\text{ex}(n, \pi)$, where $P$ is the permutation matrix of permutation $\pi$, means that given two matrices $M_1$ and $M_2$ which both avoid $P$, $M_1 + M_2$ also avoids $P$.

But this is really absurd and I quickly found a counterexample.

What does it mean when it first says


The function $\text{ex}(n, \pi)$ is super-additive.

and gives a super short explanation of why this is so.
Then it says

More generally, Pach and Tardos showed that $\text{ex}(n, P)$ is super-additive

Why are they calling it more general? They just said a few lines before that $\text{ex}(n, \pi)$ is defined to be $\text{ex}(n, P)$ so I don't see why the two statements are different.

1. In general, if $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is a sequence of real numbers, then the sequence is defined to be super-additive if $a_{n+m}\ge a_n+a_m$, for all $n,m\ge 1$ (this is a fairly well-known definition). So, saying that $ex(n,\pi)$ is super-additive means that $ex(n+m,\pi)\ge ex(n,\pi)+ex(m,\pi).$
The proof uses the direct sum of matrices. If $A$ and $B$ are matrices, then the direct sum of $A$ and $B$, denoted $A\oplus B$, is the block matrix
$$
A\oplus B= \begin{bmatrix}A & O\\ O& B\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $O$ refers to an all-zeroes matrix of the appropriate size.
2. First, the author proves that $ex(n,P)$ is super-additive, assuming that $P$ is the permutation matrix of a permutation. Then, the author mentions that other people proved $ex(n,P)$ is super-additive, without the italicized qualification. So, this more generally applies when $P$ is any binary matrix, not just when  $P$ is a permutation  matrix.

Hi Mike, thanks so much for the response. I thought the definition from Wikipedia was right too, but then the next sentence talks about directly adding matrices themselves, which doesn’t make sense in this context. Am I missing something?

@SakshamSethi I understand your confusion now, please see my edited answer.

I see. But do we even need to prove it like this? In a previous paper I read, and also in the paragraph before this, it states that this function is $O(n)$. Thus isn’t it obvious that we should have $\text{ex}(n+m, P) = \text{ex}(n, P) + \text{ex}(m, P)$ for a permutation matrix $P$?

I do not see why you think $ex(n,P)$ being $O(n)$ implies $ex(n+m,P)=ex(n,P)+ex(m,P)$. That equation is demonstrably false, as this counterexample shows. Let $I_2$ be the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. Note that $ex(2,I_2)=3$, because $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ is a matrix with mass $3$ that avoids $I_2$. However, $ex(4,P)\ge 7$, because the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&1\0&0&1&1\0&1&1&0\1&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ has a mass of $7$ and avoids $I_2$. Therefore, $ex(4,I_2)>ex(2,I_2)+ex(2,I_2)$, as $7>3+3$.

I see. Sorry I got confused at the basic level. My next question is, it says that $\frac{\text{ex}(n, \pi)}{n}$ approaches $2^{O(k \log k)}$. The only thing I got was that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\text{ex}(n, \pi)}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\text{ex}'(n, \pi)}{1}$ by LHopital's Rule, and since $\text{ex}(n, \pi)$ is $O(n)$ we know that the derivative of this function as $n$ approaches infinity just approaches the coefficient of the linear term, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} \le 2k^4 \binom{k^2}{k}$. Now I don't understand how they came up with $2^{O(k \log k)}$.

Instead of asking in the comments, you should post a new question.
